# SSH doesn't accept password in Windows 10 : read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

I want to establish as SSH connection in Windows 10 but following error occurred :

```
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This [thread suggests](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14523/#id_post_58850) such an error message is the manifestation/side-effect of an error not seen in your message.

> the fundamental issue was a misunderstanding of your ssh instructions online.
>
> I thought authorized_keys was a folder to contain the file `id_rsa.pub` rather than a file to contain the key itself.
> This stemmed from my limited understanding of ssh conventions.

So double-check you did register the right key (public one) to the remote account `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found your question after searching for the "read_passphrase" error, so if anyone follows... I eventually found this little gem that explains how git for Windows uses its own SSH binaries by default, and doesn't integrate with e.g. Windows SSH Agent.

Setting up Windows SSH agent and adding the GIT_SSH environment as directed fixed my tty issues, and I don't have to enter my passphrase every time.

https://snowdrift.tech/cli/ssh/git/tutorials/2019/01/31/using-ssh-agent-git-windows.html#linking-to-git

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33525297)